# How to wash/validate a string to assign it to a componentname?

Tags: delphi

I have a submenu that list departments. Behind this each department have an action who's name is assigned 'actPlan' + department.name.

Now I realize this was a bad idea because the name can contain any strange character in the world but the action.name cannot contain international characters. Obviously Delphi IDE itself call some method to validate if a string is a valid componentname. Anyone know more about this ?

I have also an idea to use

```
Action.name := 'actPlan' + department.departmentID;
```

instead. The advantage is that departmentID is a known format, 'xxxxx-x' (where x is 1-9), so I have only to replace '-' with for example underscore. The problem here is that those old actionnames are already persisted in a personal textfile. It will be exceptions if I suddenly change from using departments name to the ID.

I could of course eat the exception first time and then call a method that search replace that textfile with the right data and reload it.

So basically I search the most elegant and futureproof method to solve this :)
I use D2007.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Component names are validated using the [`IsValidIdent`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/SysUtils.IsValidIdent) function from *SysUtils*, which simply checks whether the first character is alphabetic or an underscore and whether all subsequent characters are alphanumeric or an underscore.

To create a string that fits those rules, simply remove any characters that don't qualify, and then add a qualifying character if the result starts with a number.

That transformation might yield the same result for similar names. If that's not something you want, then you can add something unique to the end of the string, such as a checksum computed from the input string, or your department ID.

```
function MakeValidIdent(const s: string): string;
var
  len: Integer;
  x: Integer;
  c: Char;
begin
  SetLength(Result, Length(s));
  x := 0;
  for c in s do
    if c in ['A'..'Z', 'a'..'z', '0'..'9', '_'] then begin
      Inc(x);
      Result[x] := c;
    end;
  SetLength(Result, x);
  if x = 0 then
    Result := '_'
  else if Result[1] in ['0'..'9'] then
    Result := '_' + Result;
  // Optional uniqueness protection follows. Choose one.
  Result := Result + IntToStr(Checksum(s));
  Result := Result + GetDepartment(s).ID;
end;
```

In Delphi 2009 and later, replace the second two `in` operators with calls to the [`CharInSet`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/SysUtils.CharInSet) function. (Unicode characters don't work well with Delphi sets.) In Delphi 8 and earlier, change the first `in` operator to a classic `for` loop and index into `s`.

Answer (score 6):

I have written a routine

```
// See SysUtils.IsValidIdent:
function MakeValidIdent(const AText: string): string;
const
  Alpha = ['A'..'Z', 'a'..'z', '_'];
  AlphaNumeric = Alpha + ['0'..'9'];

  function IsValidChar(AIndex: Integer; AChar: Char): Boolean;
  begin
    if AIndex = 1 then
      Result := AChar in Alpha
    else
      Result := AChar in AlphaNumeric;
  end;

var
  i: Integer;
begin
  Result := AText;
  for i := 1 to Length(Result) do
    if not IsValidChar(i, Result[i]) then
      Result[i] := '_';
end;
```

which makes Pascal identifiers from strings.
You might also want to copy FindUniqueName from Classes.pas and apply that to the result from MakeValidIdent.

Comment: Your routine doesn't work correctly, it accepts digits for the first character.

Comment: Thanks, I never noticed that. That's no problem if you use the routine as I do and berocoder could. So I have to decide whether to rename it or adjust the implementation.

Comment: Renaming it will not make it create valid component names - try it in the Object Inspector, "42" for example isn't a valid name.

Comment: But renaming it *would* remove the expectation that it is *supposed* to create valid component names. Its current name suggests that's what it does.

Comment: After thinking about it, I'll correct the implementation (see my edit) and call "MakeValidIdent(APrefix + SomeRandomString)" instead of the current "APrefix + MakeValidIdent(SomeRandomString)". It's a tiny bit more inefficient for my use cases (where APrefix always is a valid identifier) but also fool proof.

Comment: @Rob: Renaming it would be fine - if it weren't for the question, which specifically asked for strings to be assigned to the component name. I'd expect an answer to the question to honour this.

Comment: @Ulrich: Your edited routine is much too baroque and unclear. Just test the first char against `Alpha`, start the loop from 2 instead of from 1, and test against `AlphaNumeric` in the loop - then you can remove `IsValidChar()`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my routine:

```
function MakeValidIdent(const s: string): string;
begin
  Result := 'clm'; //Prefix
  for var c in s do
    if CharInSet(c, ['A'..'Z', 'a'..'z', '0'..'9', '_']) then
      Result := Result + c;
end;
```